# Adding It function to Cypress fixture

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, cypress, fixtures

I think I'm missing the point here. The fixture can't be used outside a test but I want to use the 'it' function to test each fixture in a JSON file.

I'm not sure if I understand fixtures correctly or use them correctly at the moment. Here is my Cypress TypeScript code:

```
let row: string;
let stream: string;

cy.fixture('AllNotificationStates').then((notifications) => {
  for (let notification in notifications) {
    row = notifications[notification].rowId;
    stream = notifications[notification].streamId;

    it(`${row}`, () => {
      cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/', (req) => {
        req.reply((req) => {
          req.statusCode = 200;
          req.body = [notifications[notification]];
        });
      });
      cy.visit('/notification/dashboard');

      co.setTestId(row);
      co.assertRowIDandStreamID(row, stream);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [cypress-each](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-each) will **run all tests regardless if one or more fail**. Depending on how long it takes, you may want to break down the it.each test into another file.

```
import 'cypress-each' // can included in /support/index.js
import allNotifications from 'notificaitonsPath'

describe('Disclaimer check', () => {
  it.each(allNotifications)
    ((notify) => notify.rowId, // use function to print out row id for test title
     (notification) => {
       // test code
     })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `cy.fixture` if you are using it before the `it` block. Instead you can directly import it and then use it like this.

```js
import notifications from '../fixtures/AllNotificationStates.json'

for (let notification in notifications) {
  let row = notifications[notification].rowId
  let stream = notifications[notification].streamId

  it(`${row}`, () => {
    cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/', (req) => {
      req.reply((req) => {
        req.statusCode = 200
        req.body = [notifications[notification]]
      })
    })
    cy.visit('/notification/dashboard')

    co.setTestId(row)
    co.assertRowIDandStreamID(row, stream)
  })
}
```